# Subversion manager with mirroring capabilities

Tags: svn, mirroring

I am stuck in a situation from a last few days, and after exploring not-so-good options, I thought I'd turn to stackoverflow.com once again.

Here's my question: We're shifting all our  repositories on LAN from web so that our developers can enjoy more speed and commits/checkouts are fast. While the transition was being done, we realized that this step has slowed down deployments, as our deployment procedure includes checking out code from the repo server - and now that repo server is on our LAN, its connectivity is terribly slow from Internet. So I wanted to know if its possible that we can have 2 repo servers, one on LAN and other on our web server and put them in sync without too much hassle?

Answer (score 1):

on UNIX you can cheat, but you made no mention of platform. Perhaps you can adopt the following idea:

- Make a checkout on the LAN side (fast)
- Push to deployment by rsync (fast as only delta-changes are pushed)

With git, darcs, mercurial or bzr, this is trivial as the distributed part saves the day.

The goal is to minimize the overhead in transferred bytes or by having a mirror which eventually becomes consistent with the latest checkin over time (i.e., you move all bytes, you just wait for it). I would refrain from the latter since fast deployment is a goal in itself (you want to quickly push out a fix).

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but: distributed SCMs like mercurial or git can do this easily and naturally. They also perform much better in pretty much every regard.